# OpenGL ES 2.0 iPhone - glClear on frame buffer does nothing

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

i'm trying to clear the screen framebuffer with 
`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

i want the framebuffer to become black.

but this doesn't seem to do anything and the last drawn shader is still on the screen.

what's my bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you swapping frames after clearing?

The clear operation, depending on how the window is set up (double-buffered or no), will likely only clear the *backbuffer*. This leaves the frontbuffer, which is visible, unchanged.

In order for any operations to become visible, you need to swap your buffers. This is done different ways depending on platform, it may be `wglSwapBuffers`, `glxSwapBuffers`, or any number of others; check your docs.

You may be able to dodge that requirement by using a single buffer, but that will have rather large performance implications.

Comment: "but that will have rather large performance implications." Double Buffering is not a performance thing. Double buffering is used to avoid the rendering process being visible like with a single buffered framebuffer, which cause a flickering effect and makes playing smooth animations infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using depth buffer (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`) ? If yes, try to clear also that buffer:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set an clear color with `glClearColor`? If no, set it, otherwise your code looks correct.

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Call before glClear()
```